# BufferGeometry : Vertex Colors changed, but not updated visually

Tags: three.js

while using Three.js i met a problem connected with vertexes colors.
I created BufferGeometry , which consists of squares made by 2 triangles.

```
var geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
// filling positions and colors
geometry.addAttribute('position', new THREE.BufferAttribute(positions, 3));
geometry.addAttribute('color', new THREE.BufferAttribute(colors, 3));

var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial(
    {
        side: THREE.OneSide, vertexColors: THREE.VertexColors
    });
GridFloor = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
GridFloor.rotation.x = Math.PI / 2;
GridFloor.geometry.dynamic = true;
GridFloor.geometry.__dirtyColors = true;
scene.add(GridFloor);
```

Everything works fine, until i change vertex colors. I am changing them , trying to update , but nothing happens...

```
var newColor = new THREE.Color(0xff0000);
var colors = GridFloor.geometry.attributes.color.array;
    for (var i = 0, j = 0; i < 4; i++, j += 3) {

        var index = INTERSECTED.indices[i % 3] * 3;

        colors[index] = newColor.r;
        colors[index + 1] = newColor.g;
        colors[index + 2] = newColor.b;
    }
GridFloor.geometry.colorsNeedUpdate = true;

INTERSECTED.colorsNeedUpdate = true;
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Could you do a jsfiddle?

Comment: Thank you for your attention, mrdoob and WestLangley.I ll try WestLangley answer, if it will not work i ll make jsfiddle.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is how you set the `needsUpdate` flag for `BufferGeometry`.

```
bufferGeometry.attributes.attributeName.needsUpdate = true;
```

three.js r.68

Comment: THANK YOUR very much WestLangley, i was so upset to remake what i have done into planegeometry, but you saved my day:)

I knew you or mrdoob, will help, sandly stackoverflow dosnt allow direct messaged to users(wanted to write u directly). Anyway thank you once again guys, u are the best.

Comment: Please can this be included in the documentation on [Updating](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/Updates).  Current version of "Updating" refers to Custom attributes (in MeshShaderMaterial) but I understand that ["As of THREE r72, directly assigning attributes in a ShaderMaterial is no longer supported"](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Materials/ShaderMaterial)